# undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass when trying to do an advanced search ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am trying to set up an advanced search on the contracts section of my landlord management application.

So far i have followed the following tutorial but still not able to get anywhere.

The search form displays correctly but as soon as i search anything i get error mentioned in title.

app/models/search.rb:11:in `search_contracts'
app/views/searches/show.html.haml:3:in`_app_views_searches_show_html_haml__746758187_75961032'

search.rb

class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

```
def search_contracts

@contracts = Contract.all

contracts = contracts.where(["first_name LIKE ?", first_name]) if first_name.present?
contracts = contracts.where(["last_name LIKE ?", last_name]) if last_name.present?
contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", min_balance]) if min_balance.present?
contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", max_balance]) if max_balance.present?
contracts = contracts.where(["unpaid_rent LIKE ?", unpaid_rent]) if unpaid_rent.present?

return contracts
end
end
```

search_controller

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

def new
@search = Search.new
end

def create
@search = Search.create(search_params)
redirect_to @search
end

def show
@search = Search.find(params[:id])
end


private

def search_params
params.require(:search).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :min_balance, 
:max_balance, :unpaid_rent)
end

end
```

Comment: @widjajayd sqllite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instantiate `@contracts`, but not `contracts`:

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base

  def search_contracts
    @contracts = Contract.all

    contracts = contracts.where(["first_name LIKE ?", first_name]) if first_name.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["last_name LIKE ?", last_name]) if last_name.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", min_balance]) if min_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["balance >= ?", max_balance]) if max_balance.present?
    contracts = contracts.where(["unpaid_rent LIKE ?", unpaid_rent]) if unpaid_rent.present?

    return contracts
  end
end
```

So, `contracts.where` will throw the `undefined method` error since `contracts` is nil.

Also, it seems a little weird that `Search` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` based on the code you've posted. But, maybe there's more going on than meets the eye.

Comment: i checked and i still get the same error with undefined method 'where' @jvillian

Comment: apologies i checked and removed the @symbol and its worked! Thank you

Comment: Also when i try search for a name i get error SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: first_name: SELECT "contracts".* FROM "contracts" WHERE (first_name LIKE 'pranil') ? Thanks

Comment: That's a different question altogether. You should post a new question with all the relevant details. I'll keep an eye out for it.